# How to animate using requestAnimationFrame?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to use `requestAnimationFrame` to animate my canvas when I click on + and - buttons to zoom in and zoom out like the Google Maps does (When you click on the + button to zoom in, you see a slight transition or a delay). Unlike the traditional canvas implementations, I have a pretty complicated structure in the application.

When the button is clicked, `zoomin()` function inside a service is called where the values are calculated and then the resultant value is emitted which is captured by a different component `A` which in turn calls a different class method `redraw()` which redraws the canvas.

In every example I saw, the images are being animated by manipulating the pixel values with time and the `draw()` method is available right there. But could anyone tell me where I should handle this and is there any alternative? And also how could I animate like the google maps does in JavaScript?

Could anyone guide me?

Thank you.

Comment: Actually, requestAnimationFrame is just javascript. It does not have anything to do with TypeScript. :)

Comment: Yes. My bad. Thanks :) I made the appropriate edit.

Comment: My understanding of requestAnimationFrame is to lock your frame rate /second to a certain number like 60 fps. The callback will thus being called every 1/60 seconds where you can use your data to draw a frame on canvas. It is more likely a callback from browser to tell you: I'm ready to draw next frame and it is the time...So basically, you call the function to ask browser: let me know when you can draw next frame.

Comment: @Keyang Of course, but I am not sure how to implement it on click and how to make the zoomIn() function to be called by rAF every 1/60th second.

Answer (score 0):

The demos that you have seen are right. `requestAnimationFrame` is a means and not an end. You use it to make your application more smooth and performant by limiting how often a method can be called, not just for the sake of using it to draw because that will not help.

If you want to use `requestAnimationFrame` for throttling (ie doing a redraw update every 1/60 of a second instead of whenever `zoomin` is called), you will have to update your logic and indeed store and update the zoom values in the background in a data service somewhere. The `requestAnimationFrame` loop should indeed have access to and call `redraw` so it is called every 1/60 of a second instead of whenever something updates. `Redraw` should have access to all data needed to draw the map (like the current zoom level).

The only alternative is NOT using `requestAnimationFrame` and doing the debouncing yourself when receiving mousewheel events to prevent to much draws. It sounds like your application could benefit from a more simple structure that would allow the use of `requestAnimationFrame`.

For the animation part, I would ask a separate question as that is a whole other topic.